# In VLCJ, how can I find a media file's total playtime?

Tags: java, vlcj

I'm writing a media player in Java using VLCJ. I'd like to be able to seek a JSlider through to the end of a media file, but for that I'll need to know its total playtime.

How can I obtain the total playtime of a media file using VLCJ?

Comment: Hi Rafat Touqir Rafsun, welcome to Stack Overflow!
The Stack Overflow Community  might be able to help you figure out the problem
but is not able to without concrete data and this is not a "we write the code for you" type of site.
Help us help you, by sharing the code you're using right now, possibly some sample data and any possible errors you encounter.
Adapt your question to include those and you'll surely get a helpful answer. Thanks for considering. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply use the `getLength()` method in your `MediaPlayer` to get total playtime for current playing file. This will returns total length of media in milliseconds.

Comment: thanks,it helped me,but i am having problem to make my player full screen ,hope u'll help me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a slider with Min = 0, Max = 100 (100%) then override positionChanged then implement as below:

```
        @Override
        public void positionChanged(MediaPlayer mp, float f) {
            int iPos = (int)(f * 100.0);
            slider.setValue(iPos);
        }
```

Comment: i solved my problem few days earlier and the solution is same as yours,thanks for helping,i am having new problem to  make my player full screen,would u help me sharing some code :)